# How to send a meeting request with Outlook VBA that will accept the first X attendees and reject everyone else?

Tags: vba, outlook

So I'm trying to write a macro in Outlook that will send a optional meeting request. The meeting is on a first come first serve basis, so after X number of responses I would like people that tried to attend after it is full to receive an email saying it is full. I'm mostly unsure about how to look at the number of responses.

Answer (score 0):

To process the responses you'll have to monitor the ItemAdd event of the Inbox's Folder object.  Then cross-reference the number and type of responses by looking at the Recipient.MeetingResponseStatus value for each person invited via the AppointmentItem.Recipients collection.